# Как сделать анимацию смены цвета фона у Button WPF C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Делаю приложение на WPF C#.
Хочу сделать для кнопки анимацию мерцания, через привязку к свойству.

Кнопка xaml:

```
<Button x:Name="btAction" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Padding="5" Height="25" FontFamily="/LK_Teacher;component/Assets/Fonts/#Font Awesome 5 Free Regular">
            <Button.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label x:Name="labTag" FontFamily="/LK_Teacher;component/Assets/Fonts/#Font Awesome 5 Free Regular" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,5,0"></Label>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tblTitle" FontSize="14" FontFamily="/LK_Teacher;component/Assets/Fonts/#Roboto" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0"></TextBlock>
                        <Label x:Name="labType" Margin="5,0,0,0" FontFamily="/LK_Teacher;component/Assets/Fonts/#Font Awesome 5 Free Regular" FontSize="16" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ToolTip>
            </Button.ToolTip>
        </Button>
```

Стили для кнопки которые привязываются во время работы программы:

```
<Style x:Key="BorderB" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ClassButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BorderB}">
    <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="#E3B638"/>
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Label.Content" Value="&#xF501;"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Label.Foreground" Value="#E3B638"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="#FAD25F"/>
        </Trigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding ActiveMode, ElementName=UCEventItem, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="True"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                To="Blue" AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:1.5" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Свойство C#:

```
private bool activeMode;

    public bool ActiveMode {
        get { return activeMode; }
        set
        {
            activeMode = value;

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ActiveMode"));
            }

        }
    }
```

Мне нужно, чтобы при изменении свойства активировалась анимация смены цвета и наоборот.
Вообщем все так и работает, только после срабатывания Trigger'а IsMouseOver (изменения цвета при наведении) анимация прекращается.
И как сделать чтобы работало все грамотно я не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Так как я понятия не имею, что у тебя там за объекты прибиндены я сделал по своему, может быть получится у тебя взять за основу.

В моей реализации кнопка перестаёт мигать, когда переключается свойство `IsActiveMode`. Когда она мигает, то наведение курсора мыши на неё никак не влияет на анимацию, что ты и просил.

```
<Window
    x:Class="FlashingButton.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:FlashingButton.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FlashingButton"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.Resources>

        <Color x:Key="Button.Static.Background.Color">
            #E3B638
        </Color>

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background.Color}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#E3B638" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Foreground" Color="#6A5419" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FAD25F" />

        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type controls:ActiveButton}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Button.Foreground}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:ActiveButton}">
                        <Border
                            x:Name="border"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter
                                x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                Focusable="False"
                                RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsActiveMode" Value="False" />
                                    <Condition Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            </MultiTrigger>

                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsActiveMode" Value="True" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="FlashingStoryboard" />
                                </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="FlashingStoryboard">
                                        <Storyboard AccelerationRatio="0.8">
                                            <ColorAnimation
                                                AutoReverse="True"
                                                RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                To="Blue"
                                                Duration="0:0:1.5" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>


    <Grid>
        <controls:ActiveButton
            x:Name="_activeButton"
            Width="311"
            Margin="57,72,0,0"
            Padding="9,3,9,3"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Content="Тест"
            Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
        </controls:ActiveButton>

        <Button
            Margin="57,114,0,0"
            Padding="9,3,9,3"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Click="Button_Click"
            Content="Переключить" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Код окна

```
using System.Windows;

namespace FlashingButton
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _activeButton.IsActiveMode = !_activeButton.IsActiveMode;
        }
    }
}
```

Класс кнопки

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace FlashingButton.Controls
{
    public class ActiveButton : Button
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsActiveModeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            nameof(IsActiveMode), typeof(bool), typeof(ActiveButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool)));

        public bool IsActiveMode
        {
            get { return (bool) GetValue(IsActiveModeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsActiveModeProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```